# Error applying image style dynamically, why?

Tags: android, image, resize, styles

attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
    <attr name="actionbarCompatLogoStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="actionbarCompatLogoStyle">@style/ActionBarCompatLogo</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarCompatLogo">
    <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item><!-- original image is huge -->
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/app_logo</item>
</style>
```

**Problem:** if I use this, image dimensions won't work (huge image):

```
ImageButton logo = new ImageButton(context, null, R.attr.actionbarCompatLogoStyle);
```

If I use this, it works (tiny image, which is what I want):

```
<ImageView style="@style/ActionBarCompatLogo"></ImageView>
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attribute prefixed with `layout_` is part of a [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) object. LayoutParams are special arguments to the parent view about how it should lay out the child view. The type of LayoutParams you set on a view is dependent on what type of ViewGroup you are adding it to. Each container view type can be different and so can the LayoutParams. `layout_weight` is specific to LinearLayout, `layout_below` is for RelativeLayout, etc. `layout_width` and `layout_height` are part of the base ViewGroup LayoutParams.

The takeaway from this is that LayoutParams are not parsed by the view's constructor, they're parsed by another step that your code above isn't doing. (The LayoutInflater involves the parent ViewGroup's [`generateLayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#generateLayoutParams%28android.util.AttributeSet%29) method.)

Since LayoutParams are dependent on the intended parent of the View it's not recommended to put LayoutParams in styles. It *mostly* works when you are inflating views from layout XML but it has other implications similar to the edge case you've found here and requires you to be aware of them. For example, a style may specify `layout_weight` for a LinearLayout but if a view with that style is added to a RelativeLayout instead it will not behave as expected since RelativeLayout does not support `layout_weight`.

Comment: I did not forget this question. I guess you're right. But since I took a different route, whenever I test it, I'll be back and accept.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to apply styles to specific views programmatically, only via XML.

What you can do is to set a theme on your activity inside the `onCreate()` method. Consult this question: [android dynamically change style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime)

Comment: It is possible, the framework's XML inflater code has to do it somehow. ;)

Comment: Perhaps, though the inflater applies a theme, not a specific style.

Comment: The inflater applies both. A theme is a sort of meta-style that sets default styles for views (among many other things).