# Android : creating drawables with CSS input

Tags: android, css, drawable

I am new to Android but not to Java. Is there already a little framework which allows me to create layouts, custom views and drawables programmatically using CSS sheets for padding, borders etc; just like Nimbus/Three20 for iOS ?

We've working on an "App-Studio" so all the views, lists etc. are rather dynamic, basing on the CSS the user created by a visual style template editor.

And if not, would you recommend to create such Android layout xml files on the fly and then load them from file, or is it better to create the drawables by hand ? We'can't bake such files just into the build because the user needs to be able to change the style in real-time on the device.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Partial ans only to:

```
And if not, would you recommend to create such Android layout xml files on the flyand then
load them from file, or is it better to create the drawables by hand ?
```

I dont think you can create layout xml files on the fly and load them in the running app. They have to be created prior to compilation of the app.

Android uses [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). Reading about these will help you generate some common patterns which you can use in your context. Once you have some patterns you can create these xmls using some automation tool prior to compilation (and avoid writing them by hand...:), funny computer changed the definition of by hand).

Comment: thank you, there seems something possible :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime.

Comment: wat you mean? Is something i am saying not possible, is actually possible? As link above is saying the same thing i am saying. All of these styles has to be there before compilation. You can only switch between existing styles.