# Android change the List view theme at runtime

Tags: android, listview, styles

Can anyone give me some idea or code if possible regarding how to change the Theme of Listview ( like the back ground color, text color, icons etc) by clicking a button for example at runtime?

I saw an example here [android dynamically change style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime).

I want to know if something similar is possible for List Views?

Thank You.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Can we use styles for List View?

Comment: Can we dynamically change styles for the Listview?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the Bg color, you can set it dynamically.

`mListView.setBackgroundColor(mColor); //`[doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)

For changing the design in your `listView`, you have to set some variables, then use them in your custom `adapter`. When you click, you change these variables and call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to customize the look and feel of the rows (individually or all) dynamically. If so, using a custom adapter and overriding the getView(...) function will probably work for you.

A quick explanation is available at http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey... I want to change the list view background color, Text color etc when I click on a button.