# change style attribute at runtime

Tags: android, bitmap, styles, themes

I set the application theme using the following style

```
    <style name="Background1" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bigl_2</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

using this method :

```
setTheme(R.style.background1);
```

Here my requirement is I want to change the theme with a bitmap image, how can I do it at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: Well, i see the same kind of question just now!!! at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832574/set-style-in-theme-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the same question: [android dynamically change style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime)

As it seems to me, the matter is that generic style attributes can force screen re-layouting, so there is no API to change styles at runtime - you need to create screen anew (the same approach is dictated for landscape/portrait screen orientation changes, where Activity is re-created and large brains of Android system architects invented savedState in onCreate() to easy (complicate?) that process, and then invented Fragments to easy that even more))

So, changing styles generally means changing layout. But you can change Theme attributes at runtime (per the link above - I haven't tried myself), and it will work since it doesn't need re-layouting.

As a workaround, since you will need to recreate views for new layout, you can simplify code by applying different Theme, see the link.