# How to change styles dynamically in android

Tags: android

I would like to change myTheme color dynamically. I need to replace the color #FF0000 with my dynamically generated color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This question isn't an exact duplicate, but some of the suggestions here may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programatically

Comment: Do you want to change theme for the entire app? or just the Activity?

Comment: @User12111111 entire app that color want to change

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime, you cannot do it in runtime.