# Change text color in style theme by code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can i change the textcolor of all `TextView` by changing the textcolor of theme (which is mentioned in style) programmatically??

Example 
Suppose I want to change the setting in my android application

I have a spinner , and I fill it with different color name.
Then how can i change the textcolor of **ALL** textviews by selected item of spinner.

my default theme is:

```
<style name="styleN" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
     <item name="android:textColor">#3DAAB9</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime

Comment: Make different types of theme of color for TextView and change it while changing spinner value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390025/1318946

Comment: I make a different theme like for red color

Comment: <style name="styleRED" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
 
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style><br/> and in programming i set like    String getcol = spinbset.getSelectedItem().toString();
       if(getcol.equals("Red")){
        TextView textView;
     this.setTheme(R.style.styleRED);
    
 textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
         textView.setTextColor(R.style.styleRED);
       
       
       }

Comment: but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Steps do achieve what you are aiming :

1) Create different themes corresponding to each item in the spinner in `styles.xml`. Let these themes define the different textcolors you want to set.

2) Then, when an item is selected from the spinner, use the following line of code to change     the theme of your activity :

```
 this.setTheme(R.style.yourcorrespondingtheme);
```

Comment: give a error : "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setTheme(int) from the type ContextThemeWrapper"

Comment: check my edit, I'm assuming that you are calling `setTheme()` from your activity

Comment: It is not working.and by this code can i change the textcolor of all textview which is using in my application

Comment: can i set the color using color picker have you any code for this

Comment: post your full code where you are trying to change the theme

Comment: this.setTheme(R.style.yourcorrespondingtheme); by using this code it can change the color only spinner list item,but i want to change the color of all textview which is using in app

Comment: case R.id.spinback:
    
       ((TextView) spinbset.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
       String getcol = spinbset.getSelectedItem().toString();
       if(getcol.equals("Red")){
     this.setTheme(R.style.styleRED);
       }
       if(getcol.equals("Green")){
      this.setTheme(R.style.styleGreen);
        }
       break;
  }}

Comment: this is my code ,by this code i can change the color of only spinner item of id spinback but i want to change the color of all textview which is use in my whole project by select the color from spinner..