# Change the color of multiple textView's in java

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change the color of many `textView` at once programatically. Ideally instead of referencing each `textView` individually I would like to alter for example a color in colors.xml (with each `textView` having this color).
Here is some code to help illustrate:

```
luminance = (0.2126f * RGBRed) + (0.7152f * RGBGreen) + (0.0722f * RGBBlue);

    if(luminance >= 160) {
        //change color of multiple textViews to black
    } else {
        //change color of multiple textViews to white
    }
```

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to reference each `textView`?

Comment: Please include your code in your question

Comment: Good point, just did

Answer (score 1):

You can use [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

If you reference the style like this in your layouts:

```
<TextView
style="@style/MyTextViewStyle"
android:text="@string/hello" />
```

and add a `styles.xml` in the `res/values/` folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

you only need to update the color at one place: in the `styles.xml` file.

**EDIT** - ah, you mean changing it at runtime. Then I'd suggest to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390025/4751173).

Comment: Can I change the styles in java?  I have a slider and when it goes below a certain point i want the multiple textViews to change colour from black to white.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your original question. You should still use styles and switch them dynamically as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390025/4751173).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

you can set custom color to each part of your textview
here is an example:

> `TextView myTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>       String  textString = "this is a test text for you"; 
>       Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
>          spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 4, 12,         Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
>       myTV.setText(spanText);`