# Method of TextView that called when Textview appears screen?

Tags: android, textview

So basically what I need is that I need to update whole application `TextView`'s font size and I don't want to create one by one variable for all `TextView`.

I try to extend `TextView` but seem can't find any method that is called everytime TextView appears on screen.

Tried this one:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

That method seems only called when `TextView` first appears on screen or I call `setTextSize`.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this text view in some scroll view?

Comment: how would this textview disappear or reappear on screen? is it in a scrollview or does the entire activity/fragment appear/disappear?

Comment: the activity/fragment appear and disappear

Answer (score 1):

Tranversals life cycle events: `animate -> measure -> layout -> draws`

A view or activity can retrigger the measure and layout pass with a call to the `requestLayout()` method.

After the measure and layout calculation, the views draw themselves. This operation can be triggered with the `invalidate()` method from the View class.

You need call invalidate() to update TextView on screen

Comment: So I still need to create all variables or findViewById for each my TextView I assume?

Comment: if you only apply some property as font size to all textview i think you don't need custom textview, only put them to a style and put this style to xml. And  you don't create variable.

Comment: If have some property that TextView has not, you can add them to a attribute (xml file) and get them on custom textview and you can add these property to a style and everything same with original as I said

Comment: I have tried the answer by Janarthanan from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime, but the font size isn't changed.

Comment: following exact way in that answer but it seems the style is not applied

Comment: got it works, previously because of I set android:textSize in the TextView's XML, but still doesn't managed it works to change the style not in OnCreate method.

Comment: i dont understand, you can add style on layout file by style="@style/<yourstyle>" why you need add it dynamically

Comment: as I check code, setTextAppearance() put each property set in style to textview and call invalidate() so that you can call it any where. Not only onCreate()

Comment: Using setTextAppearance need me to call all the TextView right?

Answer (score 0):

If the textview is in scroll view, you can use the below code to identify whether your text view currently in visible region of the screen.

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
if (textView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
    // textView is within the visible window
} else {
    // textView is not within the visible window
}
```