# how to change font size dynamically at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

I have one spinner which has some font size 14dp,16dp etc. when i select value from spinner
I want to change font size in text view for all activity of application at run time. 
IS this possible?

I refer several answer but it doesn't work for me..

[android dynamically change style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
package com.packegename;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidTextSize extends Activity {

 String[] optUnit = {"COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP",
      "COMPLEX_UNIT_IN",
      "COMPLEX_UNIT_MM",
      "COMPLEX_UNIT_PT",
      "COMPLEX_UNIT_PX",
      "COMPLEX_UNIT_SP"};

 int[] valueUnit = { TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
      TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN,
      TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM,
      TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT,
      TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
      TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP};

 String[] optSize ={"0.05", "0.1", "0.25", "0.5", "1", "4", "8", "10", "14", "16", "20", "30"};
 float[] valueSize = {0.05f, 0.1f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 1f, 4f, 8f, 10f, 14f, 16f, 20f, 30f};

 Spinner selUnit, selSize;
 TextView textOut;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        selUnit = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selunit);
        selSize = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selsize);
     textOut = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textout);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterUnit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, optUnit);
     adapterUnit.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     selUnit.setAdapter(adapterUnit);
     selUnit.setOnItemSelectedListener(selUnitOnItemSelectedListener);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSize = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, optSize);
     adapterSize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     selSize.setAdapter(adapterSize);
     selSize.setOnItemSelectedListener(selSizeOnItemSelectedListener);
    }

    private Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener selUnitOnItemSelectedListener
    = new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   updateTextSize();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};

 private Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener selSizeOnItemSelectedListener
 = new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   updateTextSize();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};

 private void updateTextSize(){
  int unit = valueUnit[selUnit.getSelectedItemPosition()];
  String strUnit = optUnit[selUnit.getSelectedItemPosition()];
  float size = valueSize[selSize.getSelectedItemPosition()];
  String strSize = optSize[selSize.getSelectedItemPosition()];

  textOut.setTextSize(unit, size);
  textOut.setText(strUnit + " : " + strSize); 
 }   
}
```

above code is working for one activity and for single textview or other view ..
use this code globally for whole application activity modify

create one class. **TextFontSize.class**  implement class with serializable

change *`updateTextSize()`* to.

```
 public static void updateTextView(TextView theTextView, float theSize) {


        theTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, theSize);


    }

    public static void updateEditText(EditText theEditText, float theSize) {


        theEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, theSize);


    }
```

and any other Layout view just create method as above.

and use this function any activity of your application like

```
private void setAllFontSizeOf(float theSize) {
        TextVFontsize.updateTextView(textview, theSize); 

       TextFontSize.updateEditText(Edittext,theSize);

    }
```

and finally declare this method to particular activity.

Comment: possible to change size in dp?